# How to generate serial number

Tags: java

.In Row 3, column 6(Heading) i have created a column where the serial number(Row 4 , cell 12) needs to be filled from 1 till how many ever records it has. I searched on how it works but i couldnt get how it is done. can someone please help in this.

```
Row<PDPage> row3 = table.createRow(20.0f);
            Cell<PDPage> cell6 = row3.createCell(10.0f, "SL NO");
            Cell<PDPage> cell7 = row3.createCell(10.0f, "Name");
            Cell<PDPage> cell8 = row3.createCell(15.0f, "Age");
            Cell<PDPage> cell9 = row3.createCell(35.0f, "Number:");
            Cell<PDPage> cell10 = row3.createCell(15.0f, "Address:");
            Cell<PDPage> cell11 = row3.createCell(15.0f, "PIn:");   
                  int a=0;
                  int b=++a;
           for(int i=0;i<Recordss.size();i++) {
                Record temp = (Record) Recordss.get(i);
                Row<PDPage> row4 = table.createRow(100.0f);
                Cell<PDPage> cell12 = row4.createCell(10.0f, String.valueOf(b));
                Cell<PDPage> cell13 = row4.createCell(10.0f, temp.getName());
                Cell<PDPage> cell14 = row4.createCell(15.0f, temp.getAge());
                Cell<PDPage> cell15 = row4.createCell(35.0f, temp.getNumber());
                Cell<PDPage> cell16 = row4.createCell(15.0f, temp.getAddress());
                Cell<PDPage> cell17 = row4.createCell(15.0f, temp.getPin());}
```

[image]

Comment: Did you try using a counter variable and incrementing it for every row by 1?

Comment: Thank you ,But only the number **1** is getting repeated for the all records displayed. I have edited the code not sure what mistake i have done

Comment: Try declaring b outside the for loop. Or even use i as serial number.

Comment: @Smile Yes, I tried declaring outside also still the same..i have attached the SS of the output.

Comment: @Smile Thank you It worked , I just gave the value of i.  **Cell<PDPage> cell12 = row4.createCell(10.0f, String.valueOf(i));**

Comment: I've removed the pdfbox label because this isn't about pdfbox. Maybe boxable, but from what I see this is about java in general.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a counter variable amd increment by 1 for every row.

Or simply use `i` index of `for` loop.

`Cell<PDPage> cell12 = row4.createCell(10.0f, String.valueOf(i));`

Or if you want the serial number to start from 1 but index starts from 0, use index + 1.

`Cell<PDPage> cell12 = row4.createCell(10.0f, String.valueOf(i + 1));`